# How to obtain WIFI-MAC Address of the mobile which is connected to the device using ADB

Tags: android, shell, adb, appium

Please help me to find the way to get the MAC Address of the mobile which is connected to system. I'm trying the following command

Command I tried: `C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools>adb shell cat /data/misc/bluetooth/bt_config.xml`

Result I got: `/system/bin/sh: cat: /data/misc/bluetooth/bt_config.xml: Permission denied`

Guide me to find MAC address of the mobile

Answer (score 4):

adb shell busybox ifconfig -a|grep wlan0

Answer (score 3):

Try running the following command inside a terminal:

```
adb shell netcfg
```

One of the displayes interfaces contains desired MAC address.

Comment: To get only the line with wi-fi interface on Windows: `adb shell netcfg | findstr wlan0` On linux: `adb shell netcfg | grep wlan0`